# libc++ duration hiding warnings incorrectly?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code works without warning:

```
std::chrono::duration<unsigned int> d{-17};
```

I would expect the same warning I get from:

```
unsigned int x = -17;
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
template<typename _Rep2, typename = typename
        enable_if<is_convertible<_Rep2, rep>::value
                  && (treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value
                  || !treat_as_floating_point<_Rep2>::value)>::type>
explicit duration(const _Rep2& __rep)
    : __r(static_cast<rep>(__rep)) { }
```

The static_cast is hiding warnings, and it seems to me that it isn't required for any functionality the standard mandates. Is this just a libc++ problem, or is it required to work this way by the standard?

Comment: maybe report or search for related bugs: https://llvm.org/bugs/

Answer (score 3):

This is behavior as expected by the standard. The remarks on that constructor are:

> This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `Rep2` is implicitly
>   convertible to `rep` and
>   (1.1) — `treat_as_floating_point_v<rep>` is `true` or
>   (1.2) — `treat_as_floating_point_v<Rep2>` is `false`.

`int` is implicitly convertible to `unsigned int` and `treat_as_floating_point<int>` is `false`, so we're fine.

The effects are:

> Postcondition: `count()` == `static_cast<rep>(r)`.

libc++ and libstdc++ are both conforming by allowing the code you wrote. It is well-formed. If you think it should be ill-formed, you should submit  an issue about it. This isn't a compiler bug. It may be a standard bug.

Comment: To be clear, I don't think it's a non-conforming implementation, I think that the implementation is preventing compilers from warning about issues. The static_cast prevents the compiler from warning about sign conversions, and not having the static_cast would provide the same functionality... I think. Right? Seems to serve no real purpose

Comment: @David The postcondition is the observable results of the function, so the `static_cast` is stipulated by the standard.

Comment: so ignoring strictly what the standard stipulates for a moment, would removing the static_cast be functionally any different? It's already guaranteed that if you got that far then Rep2 is implicitly convertible to rep, so what difference does it make? I fail to see its purpose, in that postcondition, or in the implementation I copied. Is there a case where it's different from plain old `__r(__rep)`